# Length extension attack doubts

Tags: cryptography, sha256, sha, crypto++, dictionary-attack

So I've been studying this concept of length extension attacks and there are few things that I noticed during my study about it which are not very bright to me.

1.Research papers are explaining how you can append some type of data to the end and make newly formed data. For example

Desired New Data: count=10&lat=37.351&user_id=1&long=-119.827&**waffle**=eggo&**waffle=liege**

(notice 2 waffles). My question is if a parser function on the server side can track duplicate attributes, could then the entire length extension attack be nonsense? Because the server would notice duplicate attributes. Is a proper parser that is made to check any duplicates a good solution versus length extension attacks? I'm aware of HMAC approach and other protections, but specifically talking just about parsers here now.

2.Research says that only vulnerable data is H(key|message). They claim that H(message|key) won't work for the attacker because we would have to append a new key (which we obviously don't know). My question is why would we have to append a new key? We don't do it when we are attacking H(key|message). Why can't we rely on the fact that we will pass the verification test (we would create the correct hash) and that if the parser tries to extract the key from it, that it would take the only key in the block we send out and resume from there? Why would we have to send 2 keys? Why doesn't attack against H(message|key) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. My question is if a parser function on server side can track duplicate attributes, could then the entire length extension attack be a nonsense?
>    You are talking about a well-written parser. Writing software is hard and writing correct software is very hard.

In that example, you have seen an overwritten attribute. Are you able to say that a good parser must take the last one or the first one? What is the rule? There can be stations that the last one must be taken! That is an attack that can be applied or not. This depends on the station. If you consider that the knowledge of the [length extension attack goes back to 1990s](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87471/18298), then finding a place applicable to this should amaze someone!. And, it is applied in the wild to Flickr API in 2009, after almost 20 years;

- [Flickr's API Signature Forgery by Thai Duong and Juliano Rizzo Published on Sep. 28, 2009.](http://vulnerabilityhttps//web.archive.org/web/20141014002037/http://netifera.com/research/flickr_api_signature_forgery.pdf)

> 2. My question is why would we have to append new key? We don't do it when we are attacking H(key|message). Why can't we relay on the fact that we will pass verification test (we would create correct hash) and that if parser tries to extract key from it, that it would take the only key in the block we send out and resume from there. Why would we have to send 2 keys? Why doesnt attack against H(message|key) work?

The attack is a signature forgery. The key is not known to the attacker, but they can still forge new signatures. The new message and signature - extended hash - is sent to the server, then the server takes the key and appends it to the message to execute a canonical verification, that is; if it does the signature is valid.

The parser doesn't extract the key, it already knows the key. The point is that can you make sure that the data is really extended or not. The padding rule is simple, add `1` and fill many zeroes so that the last 64 (128) is the length encoding (very simplified, for example, the final length must be multiple of 512 for SHA256). To see that there is another padding inside you must check every block and then you **may claim** that there is an extension attack. Yes, you can do this, however, the **one of aims of cryptography** is to reduce the dependencies, too. If we can create a better signature that eliminates the checking then we suggest to left the others. This enables the software developers to write more secure implementation easily.

> Why doesn't attack against H(message|key) work?

Simple, you get the extended message `message|extended` and send the extended hash
`H(message|key|extended)` to the server. Then the server takes the message `message|extended` and appends the key `message|extended|key` and hashes it `H(message|extended|key)` and clearly this is not equal to the extended one `H(message|key|extended)`

Note that the trimmed version of the SHA2 series like SHA-512/256 has resistance to length extension attacks. SHA3 is immune to it by design and that enables a simple KMAC signature scheme. [Blake2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83208/18298) is also immune since it is designed with the [HAIFA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83342/18298) construction.